Binary regression with error-in-variables
I try to predict the binary, dependent variable $Y$ using a single predictor $X$. $X$ contains some amount of error, due to measurement problems.
I would like to come up with a model for $X$, e.g. assuming normality for errors:
$X \sim N(X_{true}, \sigma)$, where $X_{true}$ is the true, but unobserved value.
My interest lies on $\sigma$ here. Theory tells me that there are subgroup differences in $\sigma$. At best I would like to write an own regression line for $\sigma$ using other covariates.
My question is this: Is this at all possible and what are the identification issues? If anyone could point me to relevant literature that could help me solve this, I would very much appreciate this.

Questions about your post:  1. You want to predict Y separately from the process of modelling the error component of X?  2. What is "an own regression line"?  3. How will you determine the size of the error component of X for any individual or group?  In other words, how can it be the dependent variable in a model without your knowing its values?

Rolando, thanks for your answer and sorry for not making my self clear. 1. Yes, that's correct. The setup is a standard logistic regression model, with measured $Y$ and $X$ and the coefficient for $X$ should be determined from the data 2. The idea that I had in mind is somewhat similiar to heteroscedastic linear regression where instead of the mean, the variance term is modeled, e.g. $\sigma_{i} = \alpha + \beta Z_{i}$. 3. I think error-in-variable models should exactly do this. I simply don't know if I can use it for my problem.

Marcus, I would suggest to check the following models, that could answer to your question: flexmix R package and, also, cluster weighted regression models.

This should be a comment on the original question, as it does not really answer the question. Or you could expand on how the proposed software solutions are applicable. It isn't obvious to me what they have to do with errors-in-variables regression models.

The question is: Do you actually have other covariates?
