# Errors-in-Variables model for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, errors-in-variables

Simple question: I am familiar (though don't have tons of experience) with errors-in-variables regression. From what I have seen, this mostly is used with continuous outcomes in a linear model.

A) Is this an appropriate technique for a nonlinear model like logistic regression?

B) If so, are there standard implementations of it in a package like R or Stata?

C) If not, any recommendations for creating a code to do so in R?

I have seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48625/binary-regression-with-error-in-variables) posting (w/o an answer btw if someone wants to brave it), but it doesn't seem to establish that it is in fact doable or how to do it.